# Generics with Optionals

Tags: java, generics, option-type

I'm using javas generics and I want to use Java 8 Optional .

All I need is that I can use this Optional, what contains a K class extending/implementing the XYInterface.

Here is my example code:

```
import java.util.Optional;
public class OptionalGeneric<Optional<K extends InterfaceXY>> {
       ...
public Optional<K> getOptionalItem(){...}
}
```

Eclipse shows always a warning:

> The type Optional is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with
>   arguments

How should I write this class to get the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
import java.util.Optional;
public class OptionalGeneric<K extends InterfaceXY> {
       ...
public Optional<K> getOptionalItem(){...}
}
```

The class is paramaterised over `K`, not `Optional<K>.`

Answer (score 7):

In a class with type parameters, you only specify the type arguments directly (as in `MyCls<X extends A, Y extends B, Z>`). You then use the generic types anywhere in the class, including as arguments to other types:

```
public class OptionalGeneric<K extends InterfaceXY> {
    public Optional<K> getOptionalItem(){...}
}
```

As you've declared it above, the compiler thinks your type argument is called `Optional`, and is getting confused when the type argument is itself parameterised.

Comment: Perhaps mention that the reason he gets the error is that the way he declared it 'Optional' is taken as the generic type variable/parameter rather than the java.util.Optional class.